# Any way there to get current date of location based on time zone in SQL/PSQL/ORACLE db through query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need current date time based on location time zone.

For Example

DB server Time zone -5:00 GMT and current date 31 Aug 2017

but I need the current date time of +5:30 GMT timezone.

Please help me if this is possible through a query.

Comment: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/3072991/Oracle-Time-Zone.htm

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "based on location time zone". If you mean location, resp. time zone of current user session use `LOCALTIMESTAMP` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT current_timestamp "localdatetime",
       current_timestamp at time zone 'Asia/Calcutta' "gmt+5:30"
  FROM dual;
```